# Conda new env used non conda python in mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I am using MAC OSX Catalina 10.15.5, I had multiple versions of python tangled my python environment, after cleaning up one issue I am facing with Anaconda. When I use the base environment it showed python as `/Users/falcon/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3` but when I create a new environment and activate using `conda create -n foo` afterward `conda activate foo`, it shows python location as `/usr/bin/python` can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Please include the commands you used to create the environment. For example, if one only runs `conda create -n foo`, then it won't have anything in it, including Python.

Comment: Do not read this if for some reason you absolutely have to use conda, but if you need to mange python versions and virtual envs and understand what is going on: All my problems with what conda tries to do behind my back have disappeared after switching to a combination of pyenv (great and simple tool) and venv the standard python library. Full control, no problems and I am not looking back, I only use conda in VMs when I have to in projects with collaborators bent on using it for some reason. Worth a try when your frustration with conda reaches the sky and you only manage python (not R etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @merv mentioned in the comments, conda environments do not come with any installed packages by default.  If you are merely running:

```
conda create -n foo
conda activate foo
```

Then the `foo` environment will not have python installed.  Try this:

```
conda create -n foo python=3.7
conda activate foo
```

Or this:

```
conda create -n foo
conda activate foo
conda install python=3.7
```

Comment: I would note that declaring all required packages at the creation of the env (e.g., `conda create -n foo python numpy pandas ...`) is always to be preferred over creating first and then installing.